# Flash AS3.0 - Error 1180 Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

This is my code:

```
play_mc.onRelease= function ()
{
    GotoAndPlay ("Scene 3",1)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error 1180 Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on a MovieClip object. Which is 'play_mc' in this case. The first letter is lower case and the type signature for the method is the following:

```
gotoAndPlay(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void
```

So you should actually have **gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");**
Finally, If you are using AS2 you should use the **this** keyword to call the method if you want **gotoAndPlay** to run on 'play_mc'. Otherwise, if you leave it out the method will run on the main timeline. So I would keep that in mind.

Also, if you are on AS3 you should use addEventHanlder. Either solution makes it more clear on the scope of the method being called and makes the code more flexible.

Here is the [MovieClip AsDoc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29)

Here is the [Reference to AS3 Event Handling](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no **GotoAndPlay**. But there is **gotoAndPlay** :)

Comment: ok. i edited it already but theres a new error. Implicit Coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String

Answer (score 1):

order of parameters is wrong. must change order.

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
```